# Cannot access a closed store pointer

Tags: objectbox, flutter-objectbox

In object box database for flutter, sometimes while referring to ToOne relationship, I get this error. What does it signify and how to prevent it? Can't reproduce the code as it happens occasionally.

Comment: Would need to see what you're doing and the error, but it sounds like you're attempting to access a closed store.  So if you initialized it somewhere, are you accidently closing it?

Comment: If you previously followed our example for this, we have updated it to show how to keep a single store open throughout the lifetime of the app: https://docs.objectbox.io/getting-started#create-a-store Previously the store was tied to the lifetime of a single page, which is probably not what most want to happen.